# expressjs setting tls connect https nginx server for request

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

How can set the request of expressjs to properly identify a TLS connection with https nginx server so that I can perform authentication through `getPeerCertificate`?

this is my nginx config to transfer request to expressjs api

```
location /api {

    proxy_pass http://10.88.132.14:4337/api;     

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
}
```

Comment: You're trying to configure nginx with your express app?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo yes. i need configure nginx transfer the tls of client request to express app. so in the express app i can use method getpeercertificate to get user ssl CSR

Comment: I don't think you can. Not 100% sure but it seems to me nginx has convert `https` connection back to `http` before passing to node.js.

Comment: @hackape - The certificate can be passed through `proxy_set_header   X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;` unfortunately it seems that the implementation of `getPeerCertificate` in [node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/908292cf1f551c614a733d858528ffb13fb3a524/lib/_tls_wrap.js#L776) doesn't allow that. I guess one could create an object that *fakes* the connection but this would be a rather daunting task and probably fragile...

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the SSL-token and then manually decode it. You pass it through adding `X-SSL-CERT` with the `$ssl_client_escaped_cert`. Make sure you are using Nginx 1.13 or later as the `$ssl_client_escaped_cert` didn't exist in 1.12.

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://10.88.132.14:4337/api;     
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
    proxy_set_header    X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
}
```

Now you can't use `getPeerCertifice()` as this requires the full SSL-connection. Instead you decode the `x-ssl-cert` header from above using the `x509` package:

```
let cert = req.headers['x-ssl-cert'];
try {
  cert = decodeURIComponent(cert);
  console.log(x509.getSubject(cert));
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Bad SSL-certificate?', error);
}
```