# How to decode an X.509 subject (from client certificates) in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, x509certificate

**Question**: How do I decode the [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) subject data from a certificate string in NodeJS?

### Background

When using Nginx as a reverse proxy I can get Nginx to verify the client certificate using the following setup:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate        /path/to/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /path/to/server.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /path/to/client_certificates.crt;
    ssl_verify_client      optional_no_ca;
    ssl_verify_depth       2;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 60m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DHE+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5';

    server_name some_server;
    root /path/to/www;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass         http://my_api_server:1234/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
    }
}
```

Now this populates the header so that I can retrieve the certificate in the header:

```
let cert = req.headers['x-ssl-cert'];
cert = decodeURI(cert);
const interestingStuff = x509.getSubject(cert);
```

Now unfortunately the [x509](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x509)-package doesn't seem to allow `cert` to be a string or I'm making some kind of mistake. The error produced is: `Error: Context creation failed: File doesn't exist.: 233123-123123-123123`.

#### Hints

This [issue](https://github.com/Southern/node-x509/issues/67) hints that it needs to have proper newline characters but when running JSON.stringify it looks fine: `"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nASDWQESAD..\n..ASDASD\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"`

#### Other stuff

*Note*: this is trivial in plain NodeJS when not using a proxy and directly configuring the `ca` in the `https` as the [getPeerCertificate()](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getpeercertificate_detailed) returns an object with a `subject` element.

This question is in part related to: [expressjs setting tls connect https nginx server for request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161254/expressjs-setting-tls-connect-https-nginx-server-for-request)

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be the `decodeURI`. The most obvious hint was that each line in the certificate should have the same max length, 64 characters. Using [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) solved this issue.

Probably also good to encapsulate the `decodeURIComponent` in a try-catch statement.